# Facebook Jan 2013 breaking changes

Tags: facebook, filter, dialog, apprequests

Here is the few lines from FB roadmap:

```
The following changes will go into effect on January 8, 2014:

    Removing the ability to "Select All" or "Pre-Select" for Requests
    As part of our efforts to improve user sentiment, we have updated our platform policy so that apps may not offer a select all option or pre-select multiple recipients to receive requests. Other Request dialog functionality will remain the same.
```

Is this a dialog option itself, or i can use this options in 'filter' properpty when show this dialog through FB JS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

As of November 21, the policy change has been cancelled:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/11/21/platform-updates--new-design-for-follow-button-and-like-box--ios-sdk-improvements-and-more/
They may still change it in the future, however.